# Is git grep buggy - disable parallel search?

Tags: git

If I run a `git grep` command n times, I get errors about 0.8 * n times.

```
$ git grep foo_bar_search `git rev-list HEAD` -- dir/subdir >/dev/null
fatal: unable to read tree (bc9e3369c6d6f027075e794fa11db02af3f8fb38)
$ git grep foo_bar_search `git rev-list HEAD` -- dir/subdir >/dev/null
fatal: unable to read tree (473a47dd3895b1db09baf4cf9463f4cbd224d5dd)
$ git grep foo_bar_search `git rev-list HEAD` -- dir/subdir >/dev/null
$ git grep foo_bar_search `git rev-list HEAD` -- dir/subdir >/dev/null
fatal: unable to read tree (b917adbfffd1928c8f6ac0f746a4fdfcf2088029)
$ git grep foo_bar_search `git rev-list HEAD` -- dir/subdir >/dev/null
fatal: unable to read tree (473a47dd3895b1db09baf4cf9463f4cbd224d5dd)
```

What I've tried

1. run as superuser to exclude any problems with file protections
2. `git fsck` reports nothing bad just a couple of dangling objects
3. cloned the repo, no errors on cloning, but `git grep` shows the same behavior in the clone again.
4. look at some of the reported SHA1s using `git cat-file`, seem to be all fine
5. Googled a bit

The most interesting Google hit was:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg164520.html

The message was just 3 hours old. Well, if they have race conditions in `git grep`, that could explain everything. So do they do search in parallel on several cores? (I have 4 here.) How could I disable that, short of booting the whole machine with only 1 core?

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.4
```

(That's what came with OpenSUSE 11.4)

Comment: (Or compiling the proposed update, or recompiling Git with NO_PTHREADS defined.)

Comment: Thanks, the NO_PTHREADS sounds useful. Not sure when the patch on the mailing list will appear in their repo (if at all). Currently I need to concentrate a bit on my work and didn't intend to play with patches for the tools.

Comment: It looks like the upcoming 1.7.8 release will include the patch.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like any of the following conditions will disable threads in git-grep:

- `-O` is given to open the matching files in a pager.
- `NO_PTHREADS` is defined at compile time.
- `-p` is given to show the function name as context.

Hopefully, the last one of these will be unobtrusive to your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Option 1 does not work at all, -O is only allowed for searching the working area. Option 2 works. Option 3 works, but it's a bit intrusive (additional output, which is difficult to interpret in my case)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, compiling git with the proposed patch seems to fix the race issue. It seems like there's no way to disable the parallelization.

Comment: Parallelization can be disabled with -DNO_PTHREADS during compilation as mentioned by Josh Lee. I did it by just compiling the source package from my distro (git-1.7.3.4) with this flag added. I didn't have time to try the patch.